# LINQ: Fill objects from left join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq.  How do I load my objects using LINQ from a left join database query (PostGIS).

This is my database query:

```sql
SELECT          
                dt.id, 
                dt.type, 
                dta.id as "AttId",
                dta.label,
                dtav.id as "AttValueId",
                dtav.value

FROM            public."dataTypes" dt, 
                public."dataTypeAttributes" dta
LEFT JOIN       public."dataTypeAttributeValues" dtav
ON              dta.id = "dataTypeAttributeId"        
WHERE           dt.id = dta."dataTypeId"
ORDER BY        dt.type, dta.label, dtav.value
```

And here is example output:

[image]

I have 3 entities:

```c#
public class TypeData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public TypeDataAttribute[] Attributes { get; set; }

}
public class TypeDataAttribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public TypeDataAttributeValue[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class TypeDataAttributeValue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

## Update

Here is where I get stuck:

```c#
...
using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        IEnumerable<TypeData> typeData = reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>()
            .GroupJoin( //<--stuck here.
    }
...
```

## SOLUTION:

using AmyB's answer, this is what filled my objects:

```c#
using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {

        var groups = reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>()
            .GroupBy(dr => new { ID = (int)dr["id"], AttID = (int)dr["AttId"] })
            .GroupBy(g => g.Key.ID);

        typeDataList = (
            from typeGroup in groups
            let typeRow = typeGroup.First().First()
            select new TypeData()
            {
                ID = (int) typeRow["id"],
                Type = (string) typeRow["type"],
                Attributes = 
                (
                    from attGroup in typeGroup
                    let attRow = attGroup.First()
                    select new TypeDataAttribute()
                    {
                        ID = (int)attRow["AttId"],
                        Label = (string)attRow["label"],
                        PossibleValues =
                        (
                            from row in attGroup
                            where !DBNull.Value.Equals(attRow["AttValueId"])
                            select new TypeDataAttributeValue() { ID = (int)row["AttValueId"], Value = (string)row["value"] }
                        ).ToArray()
                    }
                ).ToArray()
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmyB `IEnumerable<TypeData> typeData = reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>().GroupJoin...` I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - if I understand right - you have a database query that you are happy with, but you want to take the row-column shaped result and project it into a hierarchically shaped result.

---

Suppose the results are in a `List<Row>`

```
public class Row
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string type {get;set;}
  public int attid {get;set;}
  public string label {get;set;}
  public int? attvalueid {get;set;}
  public string value {get;set;}
}
```

Then you would group twice, and turn each top-level group into a `Type`, each child-level group into an `Attribute` and each row into a `Value` (if the row is not an empty value).

```
List<Row> queryResult = GetQueryResult();

//make our hierarchies.
var groups = queryResult
  .GroupBy(row => new {row.id, row.attid})
  .GroupBy(g => g.Key.id);

//now shape each level
List<Type> answer =
(
  from typeGroup in groups
  let typeRow = typeGroup.First().First()
  select new Type()
  {
    id = typeRow.id,
    type = typeRow.type,
    Attributes =
    (
      from attGroup in typeGroup
      let attRow = attGroup.First()
      select new Attribute()
      {
        id = attRow.attid,
        label = attRow.label
        Values =
        (
          from row in attRow
          where row.attvalueid.HasValue  //if no values, then we get an empty array
          select new Value() {id = row.attvalueid, value = row.value }
        ).ToArray()
      }
    ).ToArray()
  }
).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe this IS what I want.. might take me a bit to digest and try out. Thank you so much!.

Comment: Works awesome except one thing... in the inner most nested `Values = ( from row...` The number of values I get is correct, but they are both the same value. For instance I get two "Ascending" Values instead of one "Ascending" and one "Descending". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Nevermind... I was wrong.. it was my mistake. As a token of my appreciation, I rewarded you with over 160 extra points by upvoting every answer you answered correctly on first page of [your profile answers page.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8155/david-b?tab=answers)

Comment: @capdragon - please vote answers based on their individual merits and not as a grand reward for other actions - all those upvotes were detected as "gaming" the system and rep was reversed.  If you want to reward a particular answer more - the way to go about that is by adding and awarding a bounty.

Comment: (+1...again) Thanks for letting me know. The thing with the bounty it is awarded "out of my control", someone else can take it with a wrong answer but popular support, and you have to wait many days. Or there can be ONE wrong answer and they get the bounty. It's a huge waste IMO. There should be a better way to reward reputation to people for going above and beyond. I suppose I can make it, less obvious ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `GroupJoin` sytnax

There is also `Join` syntax for regular inner join

This [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/27/groupjoin-method-tutorial.aspx) has an example of group join

Answer (score 1):

```
 var q = (from dt in public."dataTypes"
         // Join the second table to the first, using the IDs of the two tables <-- You may join on different columns from the two tables
         join dta in public."dataTypeAttributes" on
         new { ID = dt.id } equals
         new { ID = dta.id }
         // Join the third table to the first, using the IDs of the two tables
         join dtav in public."dataTypeAttributeId" on
         new { ID = dt.id } equals
         new { ID = dtav.id }
         // Conditional statement
         where dt.id == dta."dataTypeId"
         // Order the results
         orderby dt.type, dta.label, dtav.value
         // Select the values into a new object (datObj is a created class with the below variables)
         select new datObj() {
            ID = dt.id,
            Type = dt.type,
            AttID = dta.id,
            Label = dta.label,
            AttValueID = dtav.id,
            AttValue = dtav.value
         }).ToList()
```

This will return a List that match your `where` statement, in the order specified by the `orderby` statement.

Not exactly what you need, but should give you an example of what you should be doing.

Comment: @capdragon Its probably a bit different that what you're looking for, but it should give you an idea what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Yopu should check this: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/

Comment: I've looked at many tutorials and links such as the one you provided but I don't get it. Can you show how this would apply to my code by filling my entities instead of `console.write`?