# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'

Tags: c#, linq

When trying to create [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12496809/442580) linq statement. I ran into the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal'
>   to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'

This is what I'm doing per @SLaks [promising answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034408/442580).

```c#
List<TypeData> = reader.Cast<IDataReader>()
   .Select(dr => new TypeData { Type = (string)dr["type"] })                
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the code structure for your `TypeData` class?

Comment: Also, it appears you are setting `TypeData obj = xxx.ToList()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>` or `reader.Cast<IDataRecord>` instead:

```
IEnumerable<TypeData> typeData = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
   .Select(dr => new TypeData { Type = (string)dr["type"] });
```

[`IDataRecord` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.aspx)

> Provides access to the column values within each row for a DataReader,
>   and is implemented by .NET Framework data providers that access
>   relational databases.

Comment: Would he also need some sort of `SingleOrDefault` instead of `ToList`?

Comment: @jp2code: Yes, i've removed the `ToList` and used an `IEnumerable<TypedData>` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why? Is the `IEnumerable` preferable to the `ToList`?

Comment: @capdragon: That depends on what you want to do with it. A Datareader streams the records from dbms. That means you don't need to wait until your 1 million records are in memory, you can start processing with the first record. An `IEnumerable` streams also. So you could write `var first10=typeData.Take(10);`. If you would call `ToList` you would load all into memory.