# Can I use Linq to set properties on List<object> from data reader

Tags: c#, linq

Say for instance I have a `List<Person>` where each Person has a dozen or so properties. The first ten properties are all set when the list is generated.

Later I need to populate the data for the last two properties on each item in the list.

I have a stored proc that returns PersonId, Property11, Property12 and I'd like to use Linq to take the values from an `IDataReader` and populate the values on the correct `Person` from the list, matched on PersonId obviously.

I'm starting with something like: (This is not the actual code I'm using, but the structure is similar.)

```
public void GetAdditionalProps( List<IPersonData> people)
{
    var peopleIds = String.Join( ",", people.Select(x => x.ID));

    using (var conn = Database.GetConnection(Database.PeopleDB))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "spGetPeopleData" ;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.AddParameterWithValue( "@Ids" , peopleIds);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var pd = people.First(p => p.ID.Equals(reader["PersonId" ]));
                    pd.HairColor = reader["HairColor" ].ToString();
                    pd.EyeColor = reader["EyeColor" ].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I wonder if I can use Linq to populate the data for each list item without having to find each one individually?

Comment: That's already the most readable and efficient way. Why do you want to use LINQ with a `SqlDataReader`? Why you you pass the list to the method at all? Normally you would create one from the data and then return it from the method.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500843/284240) is an example how you can use a `SqlDataReader` with LINQ, just cast it to `IDataRecord`. But LINQ is not a the right tool to _update_ something anyway.

Comment: I suppose what I was really wondering is if there was a more efficient way to handle what I'm trying to do here. I certainly couldn't think of one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

Though there is not much Use of "forcing" Linq here...

Maybe the join is abit faster than calling First() every time...

```
public Tuple<int,string,string> GetAdditionalData(List<IPersonData> people)
{
    string peopleIds = String.Join( ",", people.Select(x => x.ID));

    using (var conn = Database.GetConnection(Database.PeopleDB))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "spGetPeopleData" ;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.AddParameterWithValue( "@Ids" , peopleIds);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Tuple<int,string,string>(
                        reader["PersonId" ],
                        reader["HairColor" ],
                        reader["EyeColor" ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Enrich(List<IPersonData> people)
{
    var dataToEnrich = from person in people
                       join additional in GetAdditionalData(people)
                           on additional.Item1 equals person.ID
                       select new { Person = person, 
                                    HairColor = additional.Item2, 
                                    EyeColor = additional.Item3 };

    foreach(var enrichment in dataToEnrich)
    {
        enrichment.Person.HairColor = enrichment.HairColor;
        enrichment.Person.EyeColor = enrichment.EyeColor ;
    }
}
```