# How to check bool value in Rowdatabound event of gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and I am binding the data through Datareader. In database t able this is a bit field and I want to check this that if it's FALSE hide some controls in gridview. so how can I get this value while Rowdatabound event. Thank you
here is my code.

```
protected void AllUsersGridView_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("LinkButton1");
                LinkButton LinkButton2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("LinkButton2");

                CheckBox c = ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[2]);
                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    LinkButton1.Visible = true;
                    LinkButton2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LinkButton1.Visible = false;
                    LinkButton2.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use database field as mentioned below:

```
protected void AllUsersGridView_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("LinkButton1");
        LinkButton LinkButton2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("LinkButton2");

        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        bool isChecked = row.Field<bool>("[FiledName]");
        // CheckBox c = ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[2]);

        LinkButton1.Visible = isChecked;
        LinkButton2.Visible = isChecked;
    }
}
```

See below two lines of code in above code:

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
bool isChecked = row.Field<bool>("[FiledName]");
```

Comment: DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row; Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: @Deutschland: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500763/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-common-datarecordinternal-to-type-s

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    protected void AllUsersGridView_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {

                        LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
                        LinkButton LinkButton2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");

                        CheckBox c = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("idOfCheckBox");
                        LinkButton1.Visible = LinkButton2.Visible = c.Checked
                    }
                }
```

Comment: idOfCheckBox is unknown. I am binding data from database table to Gridview and bit field in database shows as a checkbox in Gridview. I want to check whether it is true or false.