# Iterating values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq. I'm using linq to [fill some classes from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12496809/442580).

All my objects are being filled correctly using my linq except for one small thing. Below you can see that for "SAR" "Flight Direction" (rows 15,16) I should have a value for **Ascending** and a value for **Descending**. But what **I'm getting are two value objects for "Ascending"**.

**Why isn't it looping through my values? What is the LINQ missing?**

## Here are my DB results:

[image]

## Here is my LINQ:

```c#
using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {

        var groups = reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>()
            .GroupBy(dr => new { ID = (int)dr["id"], AttID = (int)dr["AttId"] })
            .GroupBy(g => g.Key.ID);

        typeDataList = (
            from typeGroup in groups
            let typeRow = typeGroup.First().First()
            select new TypeData()
            {
                ID = (int) typeRow["id"],
                Type = (string) typeRow["type"],
                Attributes = 
                (
                    from attGroup in typeGroup
                    let attRow = attGroup.First()
                    select new TypeDataAttribute()
                    {
                        ID = (int)attRow["AttId"],
                        Label = (string)attRow["label"],
                        PossibleValues =
                        (
                            from row in attGroup
                            where !DBNull.Value.Equals(attRow["AttValueId"])
                            select new TypeDataAttributeValue() { ID = (int)attRow["AttValueId"], Value = (string)attRow["value"] }
                        ).ToArray()
                    }
                ).ToArray()
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking `Value` from `attRow`, you should take it from `row`.